# Affect value to dataframe respecting conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2. df1 have 5 columns id, date1, val1, val2, date2 and df2 contains 3 columns, id, date1, date2.

I want to affect date1 of df2 to date1 of df1 and date2 of df2 to date2 of df1 for all the rows of df1.

```
            df1['date1'] = df2['date1']
            df1['date2'] = df2['date2']
```

content of df1:

```
id, date1, val1, val2, date2
1,  2020-02-02 xx, xy, 2020-02-02
2, 2020-02-03 xx, xy, 2020-05-03
3, 2020-02-04 xx, xy, 2020-04-04
```

df2:

```
3, 2012-12-04, 2023-08-04
```

The result should be:

```
1,  2020-02-02 xx, xy, 2020-02-02
2, 2020-02-03 xx, xy, 2020-05-03
3, 2012-12-04,xx, xy, 2023-08-04
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('id')
df2 = df2.set_index('id')[['date1', 'date2']]

df1.update(df2)
```